# How to send response to Modbus client with using NModbus4 framework?

Tags: c++

I use NModbus4. My software is modbus slave and I have to send the correct exception response if i receive the "illegal data value". I create slaveExceptionResponse:
void ModbusRequestEvent(Object^ sender, Modbus::Device::ModbusSlaveRequestEventArgs^ e)
    {
        try 
        {
               ....
           Modbus::Message::SlaveExceptionResponse exceptionRes;
           exceptionRes.FunctionCode = 80;
           exceptionRes.SlaveAddress = e->Message->SlaveAddress;
           exceptionRes.SlaveExceptionCode = 3;

But by testing with a simulation tool I get the another response. how to send my response?

Thank you for help in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found out. The solution is very simple. If there is some error, a response exception has to be thrown.

```
...
```

throw new InvalidModbusRequestException(exception code); // exception code e.x. 1 for illegal function